# Data update problem in SQL from DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL server and I have a form `purchaseinvoiceform`. it uses a `DataGridView` to save multiple products.

In save mode this works well. But when I update any order it's updating only the first table which is `purchaseinvoice`, but isn't updating the second table `purchaseinvoicedetails`.
`purchaseinvoicedetails` saves multiple products by their `ordernumber`.
If I have one item in `datagridview` it saves successfully.
Now when I update this one item, no problem occurs. But when I add one more item in this order and try to update it, it does not save the other items.

Update query:

```
SaveOrUpdateProductDetailsOnly("UPDATE [dbo].[PurchaseInvoiceDetails] SET [ProductCode] = @ProductCode ,[ProductName] = @ProductName ,[Box] = @Box,[Quantity] = @Quantity ,[Price] = @Price,[DiscountInPercent] = @DiscountInPercent ,[DiscountAmount] = @DiscountAmount,[Amount] = @Amount WHERE PurchaseInvoiceNo = @PurchaseInvoiceNo");
```

[Here is the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwWp.jpg)

Comment: did you get any error? can you check what sql in executing from sql profiler?

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer with the number of rows changed.  What value are you getting?  Update will only change values that are already in the database.  If update returns zero it means the primary key is not in the database and you need to use Insert instead of Update.  If you use Insert and get a return value of zero then you need to use Update.

Comment: I use update to update the value but i could not add new values during update.

Comment: Why do you think a single update statement is going to update multiple tables? And I can tell that the code you posted will NOT update the PurchaseInvoice table. Your update references PurchaseInvoiceDetails.

Comment: it updates the only ProductDetails Table. But if i have 2 items in that order i can't add third during update.

Comment: please see the picture first.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwWp.jpg

Comment: The code provided absolutely unequivocally does NOT update ProductDetails unless you have a trigger on the PurchaseInvoiceDetails table. An update statement does not arbitrarily decide to update a table other than the one in the update statement.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Well....if you need to update two tables you issue two update statements. One for each table.

Comment: i already have two statement one is Directly in the form for the PurchaseInvoiceDetails shown in the picture.And second is in the SQL Procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=your_server_name;Database=your_database_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Courses", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                {
                    SqlCommandBuilder sqlcmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                    DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet(); // remove this line
                    da.Update(this.ds, "Courses");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```